# How Do You Debug a Script in the %pre section of a kickstart file

Tags: rhel, x11, python3, kickstart

**Background:** I am trying to run this script in the %pre section of a kickstart file on a VM during a 'text' install:

```
import os,sys,gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
class DisplayMenu():
    """ Create the main configuration window """
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_border_width(10)
        self.window.set_default_size(800, 600)
        self.window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.window.add(vbox)
        hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        hb.set_show_close_button(True)
        hb.set_decoration_layout(":close")
        hb.set_title("Title")
        hb.set_subtitle("subtitle")
        vbox.pack_start(hb, False, False, 0)
        label = Gtk.Label()
        vbox.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)

#        hbox = Gtk.Box()
#        label = Gtk.Label("Hostname: ")
#        hbox.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)
#        self.hostname = Gtk.Entry()
#        self.hostname.set_width_chars(30)
#        if os.environ['HOSTNAME'] != '':
#            self.hostname.set_text(os.environ['HOSTNAME'])
#        else:
#            self.hostname.set_text('localhost.localdomain')
#        hbox.pack_start(self.hostname, False, False, 0)
#        vbox.pack_start(hbox, False, False, 0)

        self.window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WIN = DisplayMenu()
    Gtk.main()
```

When I run it "as-is" it works (by "works" I mean that it displays the window and stops the installation process until I click on the close icon.)  When I remove the '#' on the other commands, it stops working, i.e. it doesn't display a window and continues with the installation.  However, the script works as expected on a rhel8 server that already has the GUI installed.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to debug it during the installation process.

This is the %pre script:

```
/usr/bin/Xorg  :0 &
/usr/bin/metacity --display :0 --sm-disable &
export DISPLAY=:0
/usr/libexec/platform-python /run/install/repo/scripts/menu.py
unset DISPLAY
killall metacity
killall Xorg
```

**Question:** How do I debug it during the installation process since it doesn't show any errors (that I can see).  If I switch to another console with `ALT-F2' & enter the Xorg command, the screen goes blank and it appears I can't enter any other commands.

Answer (score 0):

One of the virtual consoles display the install log, I think Ctrl+Alt+F3 already displays the progress of %pre.

or use `%pre --log=/root/preinstall.log` for logging.

also you can use `%pre --erroronfail`

**For more information and options:**
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/performing_an_advanced_rhel_8_installation/index

**Info @:**

**- A.3. Scripts in Kickstart file**

**- A.3.1. %pre script**